# Is there docker orchestration for Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, docker, rancher

I was looking at Rancher(an orchestration engine for docker). I think there isn't build in support of hadoop setup.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the latest version of Rancher, it has a catalog function that includes Hadoop deployment out of the box.

this is in the latest 0.49 release of Rancher for sure.
[image: this is in the latest 0.49 release of Rancher for sure.]

Answer (score 2):

One source of information would be "[Docker Releases Orchestration Tool Kit](http://thenewstack.io/orchestration-toolkit-release-aims-prove-dockers-commitment-flexibility-community-ecosystem/)", which mentions [docker machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/), [docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/), and more importantly, built on top of the swarm API, [mesosphere](https://mesosphere.com/).

> Mesosphere’s technology is the only way for an organization to run a Docker Swarm workload in a highly elastic way on the same cluster as other types of workloads.
>
> For example, you can run Cassandra, Kafka, Storm, Hadoop and Docker Swarm workloads alongside each other on a single Mesosphere cluster, all sharing the same resources.